# What does the name after the colon in GItHub ssh address mean?

Tags: ssh, git, github

For example,

```
git@github.com:JohnCoates/Aerial.git
```

in this command, I think

```
git: username in GitHub Unix server
github.com: host name
/Aerial.git: directory
```

.

So, what is `:JohnCoates`? Generally, there would be a port number, but `JohnCoates`doesn't look like a port number.

P.S.
I found this answer and by reading this, `JohnCoates` looks like the part of the directory.
But why isn't there `/`?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279624/whats-the-purpose-of-the-colon-in-this-git-repository-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't looking at an URL here – you are looking at a rsh/rcp-style address, similar to what's still being used by `scp` and `rsync` these days. So the rsh syntax is different from URLs: **everything after the colon is the directory path,** and there is no provision for port specification.

You are still correct that the `git` in `git@...` is a Unix username on the server, and `github.com` is the hostname. I think this is probably something that URLs inherited *from* rsh-style addresses.

(The original rsh had an unusual these days security model and did not allow using a different port; ssh uses a separate command-line option `-p` to change it if needed.)

So the entire **`JohnCoates/Aerial.git`** is a directory path. Why does it not start with a `/`? First of all, again, because this isn't an URL-format address and uses `:` as the field separator. Second, because the server does not require the leading slash in paths.

- **On plain Unix SSH servers:**

  The path doesn't need to start with `/` when it's **relative** to the current directory. In Git addresses, that means it's relative to the user's *home* directory.

  Because RSH/SSH are meant for logging into a *system* account, they have a concept of "home directory" exactly like local logins do. When you log in to the system, your commands start at `/home/UserName` (until you cd elsewhere), so running `ls Projects` is the same as `ls /home/UserName/Projects`.

  All software which uses SSH transport – including SFTP, Git, and Rsync – can also use this feature. For example, if you tried to clone from a simple SSH server, using the address `fred@example.com:Projects/App.git`, that's the same as cloning `fred@example.com:/home/fred/Projects/App.git`.

  (As you can see, absolute paths do start with a `/` – but they are *still* separated using a `:` in rcp addresses.)
- **On GitHub, GitLab, and other custom systems:**

  GitHub runs a custom git which does not directly map repository names to filesystem paths. Instead, it manually parses the received path against a regex such as `^/?(.+)/(.+)\.git$` and looks up the result in a SQL database.

  So a GitHub "path" is really just a custom string that doesn't need to follow any of the usual path rules. As one example of that, GitHub accepts paths both with *and* without the leading slash, as you'll see in the URL examples below.

---

That being said, Git **also** supports URL-style addresses. Your example can also be written as:

```
ssh://git@github.com/JohnCoates/Aerial.git
```

Now the path is `/JohnCoates/Aerial.git` as you'd expect (in URLs it is always absolute).

Note that although the path is different, GitHub still accepts it the same way – but a standard Unix server wouldn't. (It would *require* the full path, with home directory, to be specified.) To continue my earlier example:

```
fred@example.com:/home/fred/Projects/App.git
                    ↓
ssh://fred@example.com/home/fred/Projects/App.git
```